# WebSPhere Portal remotedcs.zip file - where to locate

Tags: search, websphere, portal

To Configure the Remote Search in WebSphere Portal Clustered environment as per below document:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Step_by_Step_Instructions_to_Configure_WebSphere_Portal_with_Remote_Search_Service

Need to find the RemoteDCS.zip.

Document suggest that, "this file is in the Portal installation under Components/dcs"

Can anyone help to find where I can get this file in my:
a. POrtal Server SetUp
b. Portal Server Installed Directory
c. Online
etc.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I did not find way to get 'RemoteDCS.zip' version 7 for WPS 7.

Now trying to download the RemoteDCS.zip version 6 from IBM Fix packs website. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

### "Portal Installation" means the install source files

Hi Kheteswar,

When the document refers to the 'Portal Installation' folder, it is in fact talking about the installation source files. By that I mean the files that were used to INSTALL Portal in the first place.

For example, when I extracted the Portal source material for Installation Manager (mine was a Portal 8.0 installation), I unzipped the files to /opt/Software.

The **remotedcs.zip** was therefor in folder **/opt/Software/WPS/Setup/Components/dcs/remotedcs.zip**

Individual systems will differ slightly obviously. If you do not have the install material on hand, it can be downloaded from IBM through the relevant official channel for whichever project you are working on.

Hope the info helps anyone else who comes across this post looking for the answer